# Armadillo initializer list is not working

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list, armadillo

I am using the MSVC2013 64bit compiler under Windows 10.

According to:

```
std::cout << arma::arma_version::as_string() << std::endl;
```

I have version 6.100.1 (Midnight Blue) of the Armadillio library.

I have C++11 enabled, for example

```
auto il = { 10, 20, 30 };
for(auto ele : il)
    cout<<ele<<endl;
```

is working.  Also the library is correctly added, as the following code runs:

```
vec v;
v<<10<<20<<30;
cout<<v;
```

But trying to use initializer lists for Armadillio fails.

```
vec v = { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 };
```

causes the compile error:

**error: C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'initializer-list' to 'arma::Col'
No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous**

Comment: Did you build it from scratch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the folder **armadillo-6.100.1\include\armadillo_bits** 
there is a config file called **config.hpp**.

There you find a paragraph saying:

```
#if !defined(ARMA_USE_CXX11)
// #define ARMA_USE_CXX11
//// Uncomment the above line to forcefully enable use of C++11 features (eg. initialiser lists).
//// Note that ARMA_USE_CXX11 is automatically enabled when a C++11 compiler is detected.
#endif
```

So it looks like the MSVC2013 64bit is not detected as a C++11 compiler from Armadillio. So uncommenting the line

```
// #define ARMA_USE_CXX11
```

Solved my problem. Now this is working like charm:

```
vec v = { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 };
cout<<v;
```

Comment: MSVC 2013 does not support C++11 properly, that's why it's not detected.

Comment: This applies to MSVC 2019. Can anyone mention why that is the case?

Answer (score 4):

The documentation says that `vec` is a typedef for `Col<double`:

> For convenience the following typedefs have been defined:
>    vec     =      colvec   =      Col< double >

If we look on the `Col` constructors, we will find the following constructor that accepts an initializer list:

```
#if defined(ARMA_USE_CXX11)

  template<typename eT>
  inline
  Col<eT>::Col(const std::initializer_list<eT>& list)
  {
    <...>   
  }
```

So my guess would be that `ARMA_USE_CXX11` is not defined, and thus this constructor is not accessible.

Comment: Yes that was right, I fixed it, see my answer. Thanks a lot for your help.